# Relationship between Base Class Library and .NET Standard

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard, base-class-library

A rookie question: .Net Standard set of APIs are a "subset" of a .NET's Base Class Library (BCL) implementation, like Mono? That is, a BCL is bigger set than .NET Standard's set of APIs?

Comment: Read the docs?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: is it really?I already read it all.. But It is not clear for me! Help-me please, so easy the answer! Its rookie question!!

Comment: It's for well-researched, well-asked questions about practical programming questions. From the [tour]: "Get answers to practical, detailed questions ... Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do."

Comment: Yes. It is. And I am a rookie. Rookie at all, not only at stackoverflow. Some tolerance is required.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image].NET Standart defines uniform set of BCL APIs for all .NET implementations to implement, independent of workload. It is the set of fundamental APIs (generally known as base class library or BCL).

Comment: ".NET Standard Library and Base Class Library are the same thing" - no, no they are not. Just because I write a .NET Standard library does not mean it's part of the BCL.

Comment: You can't write a .NET Standart library (only if you are part of Microsof's .Net team). You can write a Portable Class Library, that runs on any implementation of .NET. ( .Net Standart is a formal specification).

Comment: If you come here asking for people to explain things to you, please don't immediately contradict them. You can definitely write a .NET Standard library. Fire up Visual Studio 2017 and give it a shot. We should no longer be writing Portable Class Libraries, as libraries targeting .NET Standard have replaced the need for writing PCL's. You pick a version of .NET Standard that has all the features you need and that will allow it to be consumed by the desired versions of .NET Core and .NET Framework.

Comment: You can think of .NET Standard as an interface to code against, with .NET Framework and .NET Core being the specific implementations.

Comment: You can write library (sorry, PCL is term deprecated) targeting the .Net Standart. But you can not write a .Net Stardart library (only if you are part of Microsof's .Net team)

Comment: If you're speaking about it in that sense, then you don't write .NET Standard libraries at all. .NET Standard  is a specification for what API's are available. It is not an implementation of those libraries themselves.This is well described in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) that @Amy kindly linked you to.

Comment: I know. I already read it all. It is written in the answer to myself. I told they are the same thing because one is a specification to other (.NET Base Class Library - BCL). So, if I wirite a library targenting the .Net Standart, then I am targeting the BCL.

Comment: You're saying that "you know" but you're also stating that .NET Standard and Base Class Library are the same thing. They are not.

Comment: Strictly they are not the same thing. The BCL (of all .Net implementations) is builded under .Net Standart specifications.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, .NET Standard is a subset of .NET Framework's class library. Simply said, sorry for the simplification, .NET Framework was here many years ago, but only for Windows. Now they try to provide .NET for other platforms but not everything is so easy, so they are adding piece by piece. This multiplatform standard is called .NET Standard and is the same everywhere, not just for Windows like the good old .NET Framework.

Also note that .NET Standard 2.0 is much more closer to .NET Framework's library than .NET Standard 1.0 was. (That 1.0 was quite empty, I'd say, but this is just a personal opinion.)

Comment: At .Net world, a "Base Class Libray" is a layer of the .Net Framework (That not include WPF, WinForms etc) or Mono. My question is about the relationship "Base Class Libray" and .NET Standart specificatios. I understood that .Net Standart is a subset of these "Base Class Library".  That is, "Base Class Library is not the same as .Net Standart's librarys. Thank you. Am I right?

Comment: Ok. Base Class Libray (BCL) and .Net Standart library are the same thing. Thank you.

Comment: .NET Standart defines uniform set of BCL APIs for all .NET implementations